# Android Studio build error: failed to find Build Tools revision 19.0.0

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to import a project into Android Studio and I get the following error:

`failed to find Build Tools revision 19.0.0`.

Looking at the SDK manager, I have the following build tools installed: 17, 18.1.1 and 19.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```groovy
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt')
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        defaultFlavor {
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

}
```

When I change the build version to 17.0.0, it comes back as an error that I don't have 17.0.0.  I've compiled other projects using build version 17.0.0.

Any ideas

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems I didn't have the `local.properties` file in the project folder.  Adding it got the project imported (and compiled) successfully.

In the file should be something like:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\kristy.welsh\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
```

Comment: What should be in this file?

Comment: Something like this: `sdk.dir=C\:/sdk-path` with path to your Android SDK

Comment: I do have the local.properties file with the path to sdk. How else do I solve this problem?